# Connecting Chrome extension to server

Tags: database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that Google Chrome extension can have some HTML and JavaScript. But I would like to connect it to my server. When the user clicks a button on the extension when he's navigating a certain URL, the URL is added to the database on the server. Is it possible to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just add event handlers for when urls are clicked. You can then send the data back to your server asynchronously. Hopefully you are informing your plugin customers that you intend to track all their clicks.

I would recommend using a library like jQuery for this.

```
//bind to all links
$('a').click( function() {
   //get the url
   var url = $(this).prop('href');
   //send the url to your server
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://yourserver.com/process.php",
        data: "url=" + url
   });
});
```

You will need a server side language like php or asp to parse the posted url and store it in your database.

Comment: Thank you, mrtsherman. How could I send data asynchronously? Do you have any examples or links that I can read?

Comment: I'd recommend using jQuery or another library for this. I've posted some code in my answer.