# How do I send my history to a server from a google extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to log my browser history with my google extension and send it to my server with AJAX. Is this possible? If so, how? I am trying to do this with a google extension I am creating for my personal use.

Comment: [chrome.history](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) and [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the browsing history using [**`chrome.history`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history):

> Use the chrome.history API to interact with the browser's record of visited pages. You can add, remove, and query for URLs in the browser's history.

Then when sending, you can use AJAX to send data from chrome extension to server.

Code snipet from a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13206272/5995040):

```
//bind to all links
$('a').click( function() {
   //get the url
   var url = $(this).prop('href');
   //send the url to your server
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://yourserver.com/process.php",
        data: "url=" + url
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.